# Simplify a string with MATLAB script

Tags: string, matlab, simplification

I have a string format which looks like this (this is not always 'A' and 'number' before '_' and numbers) :

```
Eq = 'A_number_1+((A_number_2+A_number_3)&(A_number_+A_number_5))+A_number_6';
```

How can i simplify the string like this (with a script) :

```
Eq = 'A_number_(1+((2+3)&(4+5))+6)'
```

For me the simplest way would be to delete all string before a '_' except the first one but i don't know how to do it in a script.

Edit : I tried this

```
Fq = regexprep(Eq, '^([A-Z]+_)(.*)', '$1\(${strrep($2,$1,'''')}\)');
```

But it remove only 'A_' and keep 'number' iterations.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: "Except the first one" is not a simple approach from the perspective of a regular expression. Would it not be simpler to remove them all and then insert the one at the start separately?

Comment: @Will: Exactly, and deleting can easily be done with `strrep` (replace `A_number_` with ``)

Comment: the fact is i want , in the future, to do this in a loop with many different string but @Will yes remove them all and insert the character expression at the start could be a solution but for that i need to find a way to store in a variable the 'A_number_' string and then remove it all and add it at the start.

Comment: @Will i found how to do this thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regexp could do the job but i don't understand how to use it so i did like this :

```
A = 'A_number_1+((A_number_2+A_number_3)&(A_number_+A_number_5))+A_number_6';
CR_string = '';
for i=1:length(A)
    if A(i) == '('
    else
        if str2double(A(i)) == 1
            break;
        else
            CR_string = strcat(CR_string, A(i));
        end
    end
end
A = erase(A, CR_string);
A = strcat(CR_string, '(', A, ')');
disp(A);
```

Edit with regexp :

```
NewStr = regexprep(Str, '^(\w+?)(\d+\W.*)', '$1\(${strrep($2,$1,'''')}\)');
```